# Successful brew install iftop still shows "sudo iftop: command not found"

Tags: homebrew, unix

I have reinstalled iftop and still command not found. out of ideas.

[image: You can see that added the sudo iftop command as prescribed, osx still does not find iftop.]

[image]

Comment: SOLUTION OK - this one was a dumb one. If you update the /Private/etc/paths you must quite terminal and re open for those changes to be used. Example adding a new path like /usr/local/sbin

Comment: Great question, if you post your answer in the answer section lots of people will see it has an answer over time. Nothing is dumb when we can learn. I make mistakes and errors all the time and luckily learn and document here that progress. Welcome to Ask Different.

Answer (score 3):

I had to add `/usr/local/sbin` to `/etc/paths`. But that add does nothing if you do not close and reopen terminal. Terminal apparently loads paths when it opens, but does not see new changes while open.

1. `sudo nano /etc/paths`
2. Then add the path `/usr/local/sbin`, <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> to save, <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> to close
3. Restart Terminal (or just open a new tab), then run `sudo iftop`

Comment: It's actually the shell running inside Terminal which sets `PATH`, not Terminal itself.

Comment: is sudo required here ? I can open it just fine.. @jwalker

Comment: For M1 macs: it's `/opt/homebrew/sbin` (add this to $PATH).